# Form dinâmico? como fazer?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, formulário

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, tenho um `while` em PHP, e nesse `while` tenho um *form* e um botão de *submit* que envia esse *form*, porém como são vários registros ele repete esse *form* e o sistema detecta apenas o primeiro *form* da lista, os demais ele não faz o *submit*, por exemplo, tenho 20 registros, são gerados 20 *forms*, por mais que eu altere o *form* nº 18, ele irá salvar o 01.

Pra ficar mais claro, cada registro me trás um status do produto num `select`, e eu quero deixar essa opção de escolha para o usuário, e quando ele escolhe um *status* nesse `select` (que está no *form*), o sistema faça o *update* no banco.

esse é o código que o while repete quantos resultados ele encontrar:

```
<?php  
 while ($dados = $produtos->fetch_array()) {
 ?>
 <tbody> <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $dados['id_oc']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dados['data']));  ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo (number_format($dados['total'],0,",",".")); ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php if(!empty($dados['faccao'])) echo $dados['faccao']; else     echo "-";  ?></td>
    <td align="center">
        <form action="" method="post" name="teste">
          <select name="status" id="status_">
          <option value="<?php echo $dados['status']; ?>"><?php echo $dados['status']; ?></option>
              <?php
              foreach ($arrEdital as $value => $name) {
                echo "<option value='{$name}'>{$name}</option>";
              }
              ?>
         </select>
         <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="status2" id="ok" value="ok" />    </td>
         </form>
    </td>    
  </tr></tbody>
<?php
} 
?>
```

o problema é que ele repete isso 20 vezes (por exemplo), porém quando eu altero o select do número 18 (por exemplo), ele pega os valores do primeiro form (número 1 nesse exemplo)

Comment: 20 forms? Você quer alterar no 18 e ele afetar o 18 ao invés do 1? É isso? O que você fez até agora? Não entendo pq 20, se entendi vc tem algo equivalente a um grid, talvez JavaScript e ajax pudessem resolver. Realmente não da para entender a sua questão, tente ser mais claro por favor.

Comment: Modifiquei a pergunta, desculpa se não ficou claro.

Comment: Você pode mostrar onde você está colocando o `while`? E também como você está pegando esse valor no servidor? Vai ajudar a intender sua dúvida

Comment: @Peoplee e Guilherme, editei a pergunta com o código que estou utilizando, acredito que agora vocês consigam ver o problema, o resultado do while repete vários forms, mas quando clico no botão submit ele atualiza apenas o primeiro form da lista gerada pelo while

Comment: @DenisL.Murara como eu disse no primeiro comentário, talvez Ajax seja uma melhor saida.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tens algum link de algum tutorial que posso me mandar?

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem 20 selects ou inputs ou seja lá o que for, você não precisa de 20 forms. Crie apenas 1 form e coloque os campos dentro do mesmo. Quando o usuário submeter o formulário, todos os valores serão enviados para o servidor.

Outra coisa, você está repetindo o `name` entre os selects. Você precisa de um `name` diferente para cada select ou colocá-lo em forma de array adicionando `[]`.

Seu loop poderia ficar mais ou menos assim.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php while (...) { ?>
        <select name="teste[]">
            <option value="<?= $valorVindoBd ?>"><?= $valorVindoBd ?></option>
        </select>
    <?php } ?>
    <input typo"submit" value"ok" name="ok" />    
</form>
```

Desta forma, ao submeter o formulário, seu servidor irá receber algo assim.

```
$_POST["teste"] = array(
   0 => "opção selecionada no primeiro select",
   2 => "opção selecionada no segundo select",
   ...
   20 => "opção selecionada no último select",
);
```

Acredito que utilizar um `name` diferente para cada select seria a melhor escolha para dar um significado para o campo.

Comment: modifiquei o código na pergunta, mas vou tentar o que você falou!

Comment: @DenisL.Murara Vale lembrar que a lógica ainda está bem estranha, pois só terá uma opção por select. Na resposta estou tentando lhe ajudar a entender o seu problema, mas você precisa rever sua lógica =)

Comment: editei a pergunta com o código que estou utilizando, acredito que agora vocês consigam ver o problema, o resultado do while repete vários forms, mas quando clico no botão submit ele atualiza apenas o primeiro form da lista gerada pelo while

Answer (score 1):

Denis, o Oeslei está certo. Você não precisa (e nem deve) criar 1 form para cada produto.
O que você deve fazer é criar 1 SELECT de status para cada produto dentro de um mesmo form e utilizar no name uma notação de array [] ou você pode compor o nome do campo com o codigo do produto, por exemplo:

```
<select name="produto_<?php echo $dados[id_produto]; ?>">
...
</select>
```

Para isso basta colocar a tag form antes do seu while de produtos:

```
    <?php
<form action="" method="post" name="teste">
     while ($dados = $produtos->fetch_array()) {
     ?>
     <tbody> <tr>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $dados['id_oc']; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dados['data']));  ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo (number_format($dados['total'],0,",",".")); ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php if(!empty($dados['faccao'])) echo $dados['faccao']; else     echo "-";  ?></td>
        <td align="center">

              <select name="status[]" id="status_">
              <option value="<?php echo $dados['status']; ?>"><?php echo $dados['status']; ?></option>
                  <?php
                  foreach ($arrEdital as $value => $name) {
                    echo "<option value='{$name}'>{$name}</option>";
                  }
                  ?>
             </select>
             <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="status2" id="ok" value="ok" />    </td>

        </td>    
      </tr></tbody>
    <?php
    }
</form>
    ?>
```

Espero ter ajudado =)

Comment: Obrigado Thomas, tentarei desta forma! obrigado!

Comment: desta forma se eu tiver 15 registros ele irá retornar 15 forms correto, porém mesmo que eu só altere um form, ele irá passar um array com os 15 campos, mesmo eu só querendo alterar 1.

Comment: Na verdade ele vai criar apenas 1 form, com 15 selects por exemplo, ai você recupera os os valores desses selects e grava no banco. Mesmo que você tenha alterado apenas 1, não tem problema, pode fazer o update usando os 15 valores, pois os valores serão os mesmos, e os campos que você tiver alterado vão ser atualizados no banco.